# Instant app info: version display missing

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, android-instant-apps

In App info of Instant App, `version` is not visible under App name. Instead of version "**Your name**" as text is visible, even though `VersionName` and `VersionCode` is added app, base, myfeature gradle.

**Please refer to the screenshot**

[image: app info of instant app]

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant piece of code/config you are using currently to display the version?

Comment: @ASJ Although instant apps are relatively new, it would be good to include the version of Android you're using, to give all readers some context.

Comment: I can't help wondering whether this is by design. Websites are versionless; and it would make sense to think of an instant app as an extention of the website it was downloaded from. This impression sticks as I read through the [UX Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/ux-best-practices.html#instant-v-installed)

Comment: In particular, it seems like an Instant App is supposed to be downloaded every time the user opens it. So, it would not need a version number, since it's always the latest. (Once it gets installed, then it would just be a regular app.)

Comment: That shouldn't be. Please report this to Google @ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 then link to it back in here, It would be helpful for all